# Extract substring from a string having specific set of characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string

```
<span id="lblEnt" class="selected">Enterprise</span>
<span id="lblDept" class="selected">Department</span>
```

I need to extract substring 'Enterprise' and 'Department' or may be remove characters from '<' and '>'

Comment: Is your string exactly like this `<span id="lblEnt" class="selected">Enterprise</span><span id="lblDept" class="selected">Department</span>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var s = @"<span id=""lblEnt"" class=""selected"">Enterprise</span>
<span id=""lblDept"" class=""selected"">Department</span>";

var t = Regex.Replace(s, @"<[^>]+>", "");
```